# cx_freeze - How to change reference to lib

Tags: python-3.x, cx-freeze

Building an Python application with cx_freeze.

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
_packages = []
_excludes = []
_include_files = [...]

buildOptions = dict(packages = _packages, enter code here`excludes = _excludes, include_files = _include_files, build_exe = '<app name>')

setup(name = '<app name>',
   version = <version>,
   description = '<description>',
   options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = [Executable('<app name>.py',
         targetName = '<app name>',
          icon = '<app name>.png')])
```

Attempting to install an application build with cx_freeze on Linux in /usr/bin/ with application resources in /usr/share/.

Of course this results in:

```
Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'encodings'

Current thread 0x0... (most recent call first):...
```

I *think* I need to set/change the default location of the lib folder but I have been unable to figure out how to do that. It's entirely possible that I might be on the completely wrong track.

I'm trying to avoid using bbfreeze.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the code I believe what I want to do is not possible. The 'lib' directory is hard coded in cx_freeze.